# How to Debug Android AdMob Implementation

Tags: android, admob

I have been fighting the Android AdMob implementation for a few weeks in an attempt to show ads in an app I have published to the Play Store.

Currently, test ads show up in the app when I push a `.apk` build to my phone. However, when I swap to my production AdMob ID in AndroidManifest.xml and publish a release `.aab` to Play Store, I do not see any ads in the app.

Google appears to offer no way to debug issues like this. When the main AdMob call is made, they return a binary status message of the form "success" or "failure". There is no troubleshooter for android apps using AdMob that I've found, and generally no way to debug the issue so that I can figure out what is wrong. The "help" pages list about 5-10 things that commonly go wrong with AdMob implementations; these are not helpful, as any dev who has scraped through them realizes they are playing whack-a-mole.

Is there a hidden status message, error code, something on AdMob or the Play Store console that I could be missing, any warning or error that would lead me in the right direction?

Alternatively, I'll take any suggestions for AdMob alternatives as Google does not seem to support this product.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the case in your situation, but sometimes AdMob ads don't show, especially on newer apps. I had situations in which I had to wait for a few hours to get ads.

Comment: My app has been on the store for a month and AdMob has been integrated for 2 weeks so far. That's another huge problem - AdMob says to "wait and see" which is a complete waste of time if anything else is wrong with the implementation.

Comment: @Dagrooms - If you have test advertisements shown correctly then wait for few more days. Meanwhile also make sure your app readiness by following instructions provided on this page https://support.google.com/admob/answer/10564477

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Adlovin Max. Admob is lacking support.